# Example of Firebase Auth with Email and Password on Flutter?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, flutter

First time implementing Firebase Auth, also new to Flutter dev, and I'm looking to use email and passwords, not Google sign-in. The only examples I see of Firebase Auth being used are anonymously or with Google. Is there a resource / tutorial that shows how to properly set up the calls with the signInWithEmailAndPassword method?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 47):

In my app I have an auth class because I don't like to litter my widget classes with non-widget code, but you can plop this code inside your widget class if you want.

In auth.dart I have:

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class Auth {
  final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  Future<User> handleSignInEmail(String email, String password) async {
    UserCredential result =
        await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
    final User user = result.user!;

    return user;
  }

  Future<User> handleSignUp(email, password) async {
    UserCredential result = await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email, password: password);
    final User user = result.user!;

    return user;
  }
}
```

Then in my login/register screen I create an instance of my auth class:

```
var authHandler = new Auth();
```

Finally, in my login buttons onPressed callback I have:

```
onPressed: () {
    authHandler.handleSignInEmail(emailController.text, passwordController.text)
    .then((FirebaseUser user) {
         Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new HomePage()));
   }).catchError((e) => print(e));
}
```

Comment: I get an error that states `Undefined class 'Auth'.`

Comment: 'AuthResult' can't be assigned to type 'FirebaseUser'

Comment: You need to wrap the first block of code in a class called Auth so you don't get the error mentioned in the comments like so:
`class Auth {
  final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  ...
}`. Also, don't forget to import your "package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart" at the top of the auth.dart file or wherever you put the class.

Comment: When you register with email and password. Is the user automatically signed in too?

Answer (score 7):

Here is one example from my service. I ask for the email, name and password fields.

```
 registerWithEmail(String name, String email, String password) async {
```

First I check if the email is already registered with facebook or something.

```
    List<String> providers = await firebaseAuth.fetchProvidersForEmail(email: email);
```

This is not ideal solution, but you want to handle if the user is already registered, and than link email with current user

```
    if (providers != null && providers.length > 0) {
      print("already has providers: ${providers.toString()}");
      return handleProviders(providers); 
    }
```

Create new User

```
    FirebaseUser newUser = await firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
    await newUser.sendEmailVerification();
```

This is basically it. I update the name filed of the user, since I have it.

```
    var userUpdateInfo = new UserUpdateInfo();
    userUpdateInfo.displayName = name;
    await firebaseAuth.updateProfile(userUpdateInfo);
    await newUser.reload();
```

And later You can save the user inside your firestore, where user `uid` is document ID. So I can get it later.

Answer (score 1):

Git repo with full explanation example for **Email/Password Sign in Firebase** using flutter

This may help you.

Git Repo: https://github.com/myvsparth/firebase_email_signin

Full Article Step by Step: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-do-simple-login-with-email-id-in-flutter-using-google-firebase/

Comment: Hi Parth, Thanks for your post but c-sharpcorner.com website is useless. I tried to download your code added on your post page. It redirected me to sign/login page. I have created new account and received account activation email but when I clicked on  "Activate Account" button available in registration/activation email it never worked and I could not download your source code that's why I needed to re-search this topic on Google. Thanks to you but very disappointed from c-sharpcorner.com website.

Answer (score 0):

This code is for register new user

```
  fb_auth.UserCredential userCredential = await fb_auth
      .FirebaseAuth.instance
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
```

And this is for login previous user

```
fb_auth.UserCredential userCredential = await fb_auth
      .FirebaseAuth.instance
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password)
```

And that fb_auth is

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart' as fb_auth;
```